# Adding words to a Trie Class in Python

Tags: python, insert, addition, trie

I'm having a bit of trouble with a function here. I want a function to consume a string and a Trie, and add the string to a Trie.
For example:

```
T = Trie({})
trie_insert('hi',T) => None
T == Trie({'h' : Trie({'i': Trie({'': None})})})

trie_insert('ha',T) => Trie({'h' : Trie({'a' : Trie({'':None}),
                                         'i' : Trie({'i':Trie('': None})})})})
```

Here is a snippet of the code I have for the class and what I have for `trie_insert` so far.

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Trie({})'.format(self.data)

def trie_insert(string,trie):
    if string == '':
        trie.data[''] = None
    elif string[0] in trie.data:
        trie_insert(string[1:],trie.data[string[0]])
    else:
        trie.data[string[0]] = Trie({'':None})
        trie_insert(string[1:],trie.data[string[0]])
```

The problem I am having is with the else statement I believe. What can I do to fix the problem of the extra:

```
Trie({'':None})
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand why you say there is a problem with Trie({'':None}).  Isn't this just your 'terminating node' which all Trie structures have (although they normally use an unused character rather than ""?

Comment: In the else clause, I first say that string[0] is a Trie({'':None}) which should only appear at the end of the word. Instead, it's appearing in between letters. I need to figure out what I should do recursively in the else clause to fix this. My idea was to replace that when I call the function recursively, but I'm unsure as to what I need to call trie_insert with to fix this.